# How to organize work on a remote server with different versions of Python

Tags: python, pycharm

There is a remote server (Debian) that will have projects with different versions of Python. The following issues need to be resolved:

How do I configure the Pycharm environment so that changes in code on the local machine are exported to the server?
Projects will use different versions of Python. This issue is addressed through the 'Pyenv' library. Installing different versions of Python for projects. The problem is the following case:

- "I am working on a project that requires the Python 3.6 version. The path to the required Python version is assigned to the interpreter in Pycharm. Then I switch to another project that requires version 3.8. And the path to the version 3.6 is specified in the interpreter.

How can I make sure that the Python version of the Pycharm-e interpreter changes automatically to the Python version in the project as soon as I switch to the required project in the terminal?

Comment: What type of virtual environment are you using? Did you look at `venv` or `pipenv`? This allows to set the Python version and the packages for that environment.

Comment: I am using pyenv for setting virtual environment for various projects

Comment: @michael-kennedy, please, can you help me?